# Meteor call method to create Stripe customer when user/email exists in database

Tags: mongodb, meteor, stripe-payments

Submit a subscription plan form, which on the client runs through jquery validation and then calls createCustomer method. In the method, look for username and email (from the form in lowercase) and do a findOne and if no username and email exist in mongo, call stripeCreateCustomer and stripeCreateSubscription methods.

The issue is, it still registers the user to the Stripe dashboard with payment. EVEN though I receive error message saying username is taken, or email is taken. Why is stripeCreateCustomer and stripeCreateSubscription method still running?

Other than that, I believe it's working nicely. I just need email verification.. if anyone can help me with that as well, it'd be really nice. Thanks.

```
~/server/signup.js

import Future from 'fibers/future';

Meteor.methods({
  createCustomer(customer) {
    check(customer, {
      username: String,
      email: String,
      password: String,
      plan: String,
      token: String
    });

    const usernameRegEx = new RegExp(customer.username, 'i');
    const emailRegEx = new RegExp(customer.email, 'i');

    const lookupCustomerUsername = Meteor.users.findOne({'username': usernameRegEx});
    const lookupCustomerEmail = Meteor.users.findOne({'email': emailRegEx});

    if(!lookupCustomerUsername) {
      if(!lookupCustomerEmail) {
        const newCustomer = new Future();

        Meteor.call('stripeCreateCustomer', customer.token, customer.email, function(error, stripeCustomer) {
          if(error) {
            console.log(error)
          } else {
            const customerId = stripeCustomer.id,
                  plan       = customer.plan;

            Meteor.call('stripeCreateSubscription', customerId, plan, function(error, response) {
              if(error) {
                console.log(error)
              } else {
                try {
                  const user = Accounts.createUser({
                    username: customer.username,
                    email: customer.email,
                    password: customer.password
                  });

                  const subscription = {
                    customerId: customerId,
                    subscription: {
                      plan: customer.plan,
                      payment: {
                        card: {
                          type: stripeCustomer.sources.data[0].brand,
                          lastFour: stripeCustomer.sources.data[0].last4
                        },
                        nextPaymentDue: response.current_period_end
                      }
                    }
                  }

                  Meteor.users.update(user, {
                    $set: subscription
                  }, function(error, response) {
                    if(error) {
                      console.log(error)
                    } else {
                      newCustomer.return(user)
                    }
                  });
                } catch(exception) {
                  newCustomer.return(exception);
                }
              }
            });
          }
        });
        return newCustomer.wait();
      } else {
        throw new Meteor.Error('customer-exists', 'email address is already taken')
      }
    } else {
      throw new Meteor.Error('customer-exists', 'username is already taken')
    }
  }
});
```

---

```
~/server/stripe.js

import Future from 'fibers/future';

const secret = Meteor.settings.private.stripe.testSecretKey;
const Stripe = StripeAPI(secret);

Meteor.methods({
  stripeCreateCustomer(token, email) {
    check(token, String);
    check(email, String);

    const stripeCustomer = new Future();

    Stripe.customers.create({
      source: token,
      email: email
    }, function(error, customer) {
      if(error) {
        stripeCustomer.return(error)
      } else {
        stripeCustomer.return(customer)
      }
    });

    return stripeCustomer.wait();
  },

  stripeCreateSubscription(customer, plan) {
    check(customer, String);
    check(plan, String);

    const stripeSubscription = new Future();

    Stripe.customers.createSubscription(customer, {
      plan: plan
    }, function(error, subscription) {
      if(error) {
        stripeSubscription.return(error)
      } else {
        stripeSubscription.return(subscription)
      }
    });

    return stripeSubscription.wait();
  }
});
```

for MasterAM:
Sorry for keep asking and thanks for sticking around. I'm very new at this... I provided a findOne of example user's document. After submitting the form, (if username or email does not exist in db) this is what is added:

```
{
  "_id" : "WyWmdyZenEJkgAmJv",
  "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-05-12T07:27:16.459Z"),
  "services" : {
    "password" : {
      "bcrypt" : "$2a$10$u8hyzWPu6Dnda1r8j7GkBuvQiF2iGFa5DdjEoD/CkHhT0jU.IsHhu"
    }
  },
  "username" : "test",
  "emails" : [
    {
      "address" : "test@test.com",
      "verified" : false
    }
  ],
  "customerId" : "cus_8R6QC2ENNJR13A",
  "subscription" : {
    "plan" : "basic_monthly",
    "payment" : {
      "card" : {
        "type" : "Visa",
        "lastFour" : "4242"
      },
      "nextPaymentDue" : 1465716435
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you `stripeCustomer.return(error)`? IIRC, you should `Future.throw()` to notify the waiting callbacks of an error.

Comment: I used stripeCustomer.throw(error) but that didn't fix it. I don't understand why it even reaches that point in script when it should throw Meteor.Error if username or email exists...

Comment: Are you storing the email yourself in the `email` property? Normally it goes to `emails.$.address`.

Comment: I edited the post above to show what data gets input into users collection. Please take a look at let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: First, you should not query the `email` field, but the `emails.address` field(s). Moreover, your code is quite convoluted (there are more elegant ways for making Meteor calls in a synchronous fashion and other calls that obey the error-first node standard can be wrapped using `wrapAsync` to be executed in a similar fashion. It could greatly simplify your code.

Comment: I read doc on wrapAsync and googled around for example and I found this post https://github.com/kadirahq/meteor-stripe-konnect/issues/4 which says why Future is used instead of wrapAsync. It says Stripe uses custom error type and doesn't play well with Meteor error reporting. I'll change the email.address and see if that works and report back.